# Web Mobile Application

Tags: mobile, web

I finally focused the situation and tried a lot of trial on your website.

I decided to join zxing decoder in my mobile  web application which has been developped.
Therefore I am interested in using zxing opensource code in my webmobile project (not native but webmobile).

Now to be sure I kindly ask you:
-  Throught which link I can find the opensource code to use in my web application ?
- Is there a tutorial or a doc in order to go ahead correctly  and use the  open source code ?

I thank you again for your precious cooperation.

Cheers

Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

Some documentation: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages

Answer (score 0):

I read your suggestion

I have to link to a URL like this, where {CODE} is a placeholder for the value of the returned code.

Is it possibile to import the zxing opensource code in my webpages instead of calling a zxing URL ?

Tks
Carlo